# How to make font awesome icon hover when target text around?

Tags: css, html, colors, font-awesome

Any suggestion to make font awesome icon (the Youtube play icon) goes hover (change color to red) when I targeting "youtube" word? But without making the Youtube change color too (font awesome icon only)?

```css
 .fa-youtube-play:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">





                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i> Youtube Channel</a>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
li a:hover i.fa-youtube-play {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
li a:hover i.fa-youtube-play {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i> Youtube Channel</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This styles the `.fa-youtube-icon` when the parent `<a>` element is hovered over – since there's no means, in CSS, of styling the `<i>` element based on the hover of the sibling "Youtube" string – which means that individual colour-appropriate style rules would have to be implemented for each alternative icon being used, such as `.fa-twitter-icon` and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

use

```css
ul li a:hover .fa-youtube-play{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<ul><li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i> Youtube Channel</a>
</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSS selector to control the `i` tag which accommodates the Youtube icon. The new selector might be `a:hover i`. A working example:

```css
.fa-youtube-play:hover {
    color: red;
}

a:hover i {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i> Youtube Channel</a>
</li>
```

Attention: you might change the CSS Selector to be more specific to narrow down the amount of affected elements. For example `a:hover .fa-youtube-play`, or `li a:hover .fa-youtube-play`, or even defining an id name.

Answer (score 1):

Use the li as selector:

```
li:hover .fa-youtube-play {
    color: red;
}
```